# Select specific items from a file using sed

Tags: sed

I'm very much a junior when it comes to the `sed` command, and my `Bruce Barnett` guide sits right next to me, but one thing has been troubling me. With a file, can you filter it using `sed` to select only specific items? For example, in the following file:

```
    alpha|november
    bravo|october
    charlie|papa
    alpha|quebec
    bravo|romeo
    charlie|sahara
```

Would it be possible to set a command to return only the `bravo`s, like:

```
    bravo|october
    bravo|romeo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/^bravo|/!d' filename
```

Alternatively, with grep (because it's sort of made for this stuff):

```
grep '^bravo|' filename
```

or with awk, which works nicely for tabular data,

```
awk -F '|' '$1 == "bravo"' filename
```

The first two use a regular expression, selecting those lines that match it. In `^bravo|`, `^` matches the beginning of the line and `bravo|` the literal string `bravo|`, so this selects all lines that begin with `bravo|`.

The awk way splits the line across the field separator `|` and selects those lines whose first field is `bravo`.

You could also use a regex with awk:

```
awk '/^bravo|/' filename
```

...but I don't think this plays to awk's strengths in this case.

Comment: Oh, I thought you first had `sed -n '/bravo/p'` .. That's why I gave my answer to have an alternative. I overlooked that... You where first, +1 :)

Comment: @hek2mgl I had a typo in the sed solution at first and didn't see it right away; you probably came in before I fixed it.

Comment: I know that sed and awk are both powerful, but I have enough trouble with just sed! Thanks though, info always appreciated.

Comment: the grep with a pipe will not returning empty line also or having a problem (return nothing on my aix)?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu No. It would if the `|` were escaped, same as in sed (or if you used `egrep`, same as in `sed` with extended regex syntax).

Comment: @Wintermute ok, i don't have a linux distro for testing and on my aix/ksh it failed like this and i should escape it. Thnaks for the precision

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^bravo|/p' filename
```

`-n` option => no printing by default.
If line begins with `bravo|`, print it (`p`)

Comment: Plain and simple - thanks! Oh, and thanks for tidying up my question too!!

Answer (score 1):

2 way (at least) with sed

removing unwanted line

```
sed '/^bravo\|/ !d' YourFile
```

Printing only wanted lines

```
sed -n '/^bravo\|/ p' YourFile
```

- if no other constraint or action occur, both are the same and a grep is better.
- If there will be some action after, it could change the performance where a `d` cycle directly to the next line and a `p` will print then continue the following action.

  - Note the escape of pipe is needed for GNU sed, not on posix version